# views3 error with contextual filter

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to show user posts in their profile with views 3 by following this post  http://drupal.org/node/228959#comment-4591334

after i add the following code to the contextual filter

```
if (arg(0) == 'user' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  return array(arg(1));
}
```

and it works, but also giving this error

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in views_handler_argument_numeric->title() 
(line 77 of /test_drupal/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_argument_numeric.inc).

Warning: html_entity_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, 
array given in decode_entities() (line 429 of test_drupal/includes/unicode.inc).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's expecting a string, but your code is returning an array.

Try changing your code to the following:

```
if (arg(0) == 'user' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  return arg(1);
}
```

That should return the string value rather than returning `[0] => uid`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on the same line (unicode.inc, line 429) when I embedded a view from within a template the wrong way. My code was:

```
<?php print views_embed_view('view_name', 'display_name', array(4, 2) ); ?>
```

The arguments should not be passed as an array, but as normal arguments after the first two, this solved the errors:

```
<?php print views_embed_view('view_name', 'display_name', array(4, 2) ); ?>
```

Comment: What is the difference between those two lines?